# flutter WebChromeClient equivalent, to use openFileChooser and onShowFileChooser

Tags: flutter, webview, webchromeclient, flutterwebviewplugin, webviewscaffold

I'm trying to override the openFileChooser/[onShowFileChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri%5B%5D%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams))/(equivalent on IOS as well), using flutter while inside a webview (i've used [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)).

Is there a way to do this using only flutter? (if not, i'll have to find a solution for both IOS and android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

On Android, it implements the `openFileChooser`/`onShowFileChooser`, so you can use `<input type="file">` or `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>` (see [How to enable the usage of camera for HTML inputs such as `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview#how-to-enable-the-usage-of-camera-for-html-inputs-such-as-input-typefile-acceptimage-capture)).

Comment: Is there an iOS equivalent?

Comment: How do I get callback inside inappwebview when user pressed on file chooser?